# How do I load an image from a variable in Twig? (With AsseticBundler)

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4, assetic

I am trying to loop through an array with strings and use those strings in my image source path. That way I can display a different image for every loop.

This is a piece of code that works, but only with a set string, which means I can't make this all too dynamic this way:

```
{% image 'img/appel ijs.jpg' %}
    <img class="recept-image-custom" src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endimage %}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td scope="col">
            {% image ('img/' ~ item.name ~ '.jpg') %}
                <img class="recept-image-custom" src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
            {% endimage %}
        <td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When I do this I get the following error: 
`Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "("`

Beware that I am still quite new to twig so excuse me if this is completely wrong. I already have tried asset(''), but this way I can not access my web folder when I run the server.

Comment: Try this: `{% set img = 'img/'~item.name~'.jpg' %}{% image img %}....{% endimage %}`

Comment: Hi, I have tried that before and that gives me the following an unexpected token error. This is what I get when I attempt your suggestion:

`Unexpected token "name" of value "img"`

I assume you can only manually enter strings in there. Quite strange and I'm not sure what to do with this...

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/163#issuecomment-13019106). It's not possible indeed, u'd need to resort to `asset()`

Comment: Ah okay, that is unfortunate. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td scope="col">
            <img class="recept-image-custom" src="{{ asset('img/' ~ item.name ~ '.jpg') }}"/>
        <td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did that and it only works when I manually go to my php files from localhost. When I run `php bin/console server:run` it doesn't. Somehow the assetic bundler is unable to load images from my web folder.

The solution you posted is what I am using now as a fallback.

I might be missing something, haha